# Billing info becomes primary

Tags: wordpress, iats, billingblock, primary

We are using CiviCRM 5.58.1 on WordPress 6.2
We use the iATS extension for credit card payments.

The issue is if someone purchases a membership via the iATS form, their billing address becomes the primary address and we don't want that to happen.  We would like the billing address to only be the billing address and not change anything in the primary address fields.
Is there a configuration for the iATS extension that will allow us to control where the billing address information goes when someone pays via credit card?

Comment: Can you share a link to the form?

Comment: So, to confirm, these contacts already have a different primary address before purchasing membership?

Comment: Yes these contacts have a different primary address before someone else renews their membership on their behalf and that someone else's BILLING address becomes the person's primary address

Comment: secure.narsol.org/vivante-donate select credit card payment It's just iATS. That billing information is changing the primary address when it shouldn't –